# C++ printing the contents of a vector converted from a string

Tags: c++, vector

I am having some issues figuring out why this does not print the elements of my vector (which I create by converting the contents from an input string)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //produce inputline string
    string inputline;
    cout << "Enter Input line" << endl;
    getline(cin, inputline);

    //strip inputline of whitespace
    inputline.erase(
        remove(inputline.begin(), inputline.end(), ' '), 
        inputline.end());

    cout << inputline << endl;

    vector<int> intvect(inputline.begin(), inputline.end());

    for (vector<int>::const_iterator iter= intvect.begin(); iter!= intvect.end(); ++iter)
        cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

If I input "1 2 3", line 17 correctly prints "123" to console.

However, for the same code lines 19 and 20 print:
"
49
50
51
"

What could I be doing wrong?

I would really appreciate the help with this.

Comment: change vector<int> intvec to vector<char> intvec

Comment: What are you trying to do with `inputline.erase(remove(...` ?

Comment: Take a look at [this ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii).

Comment: What is your expectation?   "123" on single line or "1" "2" "3" on separate line?

Comment: @user1438832 and Some programmer thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
vector<int> intvect(inputline.begin(), inputline.end());
```

The characters are read one by one and their ASCII values are stored in `intvect`. ASCII value of 1 is 49, 2 is 50 and so on. So that is what you're seeing as output.

If you convert `vector<int>` to `vector<char>`, you will be able to read single digits successfully but not multiple-digit numbers. Eg. if you gave the input 11 12 13, it would see it as 1 1 1 2 1 3.

You'll have to separate the numbers using space as delimiter and then convert them to integer and feed them to the int vector.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are constructing a vector of INT from a string.  The Vector stores the ASCII equivalent of the characters in inputline. " 49 50 51 " are the ASCII values for your input "1 2 3"

Below code should work, where Vector of Char is used instead of INT.

```
vector<char> intvect(inputline.begin(), inputline.end());

for (vector<char>::const_iterator iter= intvect.begin(); iter!= intvect.end(); ++iter)
cout << *iter << endl;
}
```